# Celery async_result.get() hangs waiting for result even after celery worker has completed the task

Tags: python, flask, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I have a long running celery task running on remote host. After completion the result get() method is stuck waiting for result from the celery worker.

**Rabbitmq** is used as message broker and **redis** is used as backend.

I am calling `apply_async()` from flask, the job is submitted to celery worker on remote windows host.
Celery worker completes its task successfully printing
`Task test[93a4d8a9-b6b9-4a54-8d65-365584ecba9d] succeeded in 9828.842999999993s`

But the result `get()` method waits forever.

On celery broker side, I have mentioned visibility timeout as follows. Here app refers to celery instance.

```
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"visibility_timeout": 14400, "max_retries": 3, "interval_start": 0, "interval_step": 0.2, "interval_max": 0.5}
```

On Celery client side inside get method I have mentioned timeout as follows:

```
doors_res = doors_res_obj.get(timeout=14400)
```

When timeout is not mentioned in get() of celery result, the application keeps on waiting for result in hang state.

With addition of timeout to get(), the connection reset error occurs. Error logs are as follows:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request   
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 325, in wrapper    
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\resource.py", line 44, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\OneDrive - Veoneer\Documents\sprint35\Testing_with_Docker_env\flask\src\application\routes.py", line 89, in wrap
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\OneDrive - Veoneer\Documents\sprint35\Testing_with_Docker_env\flask\src\db\__init__.py", line 
280, in wrap
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\OneDrive - Veoneer\Documents\sprint35\Testing_with_Docker_env\flask\src\doors\routes.py", line 127, in post
    abort(503, ex)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\errors.py", line 31, in abort    
    flask.abort(code)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 772, in abort     
    return _aborter(status, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\venugopal.venkatesh\.virtualenvs\flask-2pC1ju1x\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 753, in __call__  
    raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
werkzeug.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable: The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
2020-09-13 14:32:49,467 WARNING MainProcess - {'message': '[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'}
**WARNING:debuglog:{'message': '[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'}**
```

Any pointers on how to fix this issue?

Comment: The default visibility timeout is 1 hour I think. 9828s is ~2.7h so unless you increase visibility timeout you may not see the result I believe. Or it could be something else, but I would try to increase the visibility timeout first.

Comment: @DejanLekic, i had mentioned the timeout as 14400, for this situation it started giving socket timeout error.

Comment: Where have you mentioned it?

Comment: @DejanLekic, I have updated the description regarding timeout. I feel the issue is with the celery backend, because in between the result drain occurs which is making the socket to close.

Comment: @sattva_venu Did you figure out the reason? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @AmanGill, I couldn't find the reason. As an alternative, I am pinging celery for status with some time delay .

while doors_res.ready():
   sleep(90)

This fixed my issue

Comment: @sattva_venu I was facing the same issue with rpc result backend, changing it to redis fixed the issue for me. Adding sleep() with rpc backend also worked for me. 
This, infinite hanging, can also happen if the number of concurrent processes that celery can spawn are all being used to execute some other tasks.

Comment: I had a similar problem when calling several tasks from a websocket callback. I think the hang triggers when there are multiple tasks called in parallel. I fixed it by moving the Celery app init inside the callback.